# Thread Synchronization between class A and B: Where should the lock go?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

So lets assume we have class A and class B. **Multiple instances of class A are created and each instance runs on its own thread.** Lets assume there are a bunch of resources in Class B which all instances of class A needs to access, but I want only one thread manipulating those resources at one time. The obvious choice would be a lock statement.

My question is, should the lock be in class B (for the getters and setters of the resources), or will it be the same if it was in class A itself? (as shown below)

```
class A
{

    B b;

    public A(B _b)
    {
        b = _b;
    }

    void DoStuff()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            b.resource = "new values"
        }
    }


}
```

I hope the question is clear. Please ask if you want more details.

Comment: Common naming convention would have the field named `_b` and the constructor parameter named `b`, not the other way around as you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do not lock on `this`. That just invites deadlocks.
And letting the instances of `A` each lock on themselves or on their own object won't work.

1. Use a separate object,  `object lockObject = new object();` to lock on.
2. the lockObject should be as close as possible to the protected resources, in both scope and lifetime.
3. make the lockObject private.

In your case, point 2) indicates that the lockobject should be a private member of `B`.

You then still have to write all of `B`s methods correctly.

Comment: according to yours and the answer by Deniz, can I use a lockObject from class B to lock on instead of class A locking on itself?

Comment: @Nadeeja Henk's answer is good, but he misses the opportunity to point out that not only does your code violate best practices, it is also entirely incorrect.  You state that "multiple instances of A are created and each runs on its own thread."  If each instance of A locks on itself, then the locks will never block, since each thread is locking on a different object.

Comment: That's what I meant with the 2nd sentence. Edited in later. And yes, the code in the question won't/can't work that way.

Comment: @phoog so locking on a lockObject from B will work right? or will it still violate best practices?

Comment: @Henk, private lock object is better I think. However, I gave this example in order to not to put the lock statement inside the class B. By this way the method of B is not thread-safe and if you need thread-safety you can use the lock object explicitly. If you do not need thread-safety, then just calling the method of B is enough without the overhead of lock statement. If you put the locking inside the method of B, then you have to lock it everytime even if you do not need. .NET framework has examples like that (which also received negative criticisms), but I agree this is not a best practice.

Comment: Henk: but one could violate the principle of the second sentence while having correct code if the A instances nonetheless lock on a common (perhaps static) object.  @Nadeeja If B's lock object is private, then you would not be violating best practices.  There are examples in the framework where classes expose lock objects (System.Collections, for example), but it is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you said:

```
but I want only one thread manipulating those resources at one time
```

Then, yes, they need to be in class `B`. It's fair enough for the current example to be in class `A`, but since `B` is public class, some other teammate could decide to use your `B` class and its resources, and if you don't provide interface for locking in it, then what you want from the quotation will not be satisfied

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access resources of B from ONLY A (assuming there is a sinle instance of class A!, if NOT then you have a problem because each A object uses uits own lock object - this - which is useless), I think this is a matter of choice. Both works for this case. However, whenever you need to access resources of B from other classes, thats makes sense. For example you have class C which access B's resources. Then, your lock within class A does not works here. The problem is the object you use in lock statement. Think in a different way and put the object in B, not in A or another class. Instead of the statement lock(this) in class A, put a sync. object in B which you can use in lock statements. For example:

```
void DoStuff()
{
    lock (b.LockObject)
    {
        b.resource = "new values"
    }
}
```

As you said, you can also use the lock statement inside the resource getter/setter. By this way, you do not need to remember locking the B object whenever you need, especially using in different classes (other than A of course). The final choice is a design choice, I think. If you need non-thread safe version of resource getter/setter also, using the above example makes more sense.